# Which statistical analysis to use to compare the level of similarity between two large samples?

Tags: statistical-significance, large-data

I'm writing a small speech recognition prototype as my side project, which matches pre-recorded words of the speaker. So now I'm thinking of comparing two sets of data (outcome of FFT) which are two lists with length approximately of 7000-10000 each. What would be an appropriate statistical analysis in this case? I want to find what how significant is the similarity (or difference) between those two samples and if it's significant enough to assume that they are same/different. I`m not looking for anything too complicated, just a starting point maybe.

Comment: Why do you need a significance test? Why not just use a distance metric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may compute mean for each of two samples and pooled S.D. Following this, compute t or Z statistc for a test of significance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong, pooled S.D. is necessary in this case because of big difference in size of two samples?

Comment: Just the opposite, Emily: because you have relatively large samples, you can afford to inspect the standard deviations separately and you do not need to pool them, *nor should you do so.*  In fact, sometimes you can learn a lot about your samples just by noticing that one group has a substantially larger spread than the others (even when their means might be close).